# Roll back Ubuntu 16.04 to 14.04

Tags: release-management, downgrade

Is it possible to downgrade my Ubuntu 16.04 installation to 14.04?

I have recently upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04, but it is not compatible with my laptop. Most often I have to face lagging. Is there any official way to get back my Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: No. Also, 14.10 is no longer supported.

Comment: You mention 14.10LTS. I think you mean 14.04? That was the LTS release, not 14.10.

Comment: Why not try and figure out what's wrong with 16.04 on your laptop? What do you mean "Most often I have to face lagging". Slow? What's not working? How much RAM and how much swap do you have?

Answer (score 2):

There is no official way to downgrade. You need to backup and reinstall.

Something to consider. Sometimes upgrading is messy. If you're going to backup and reinstall, try doing an install of 16.04 first. It may work as a clean install better than as the upgrade you did. If it doesn't work, you already have a backup and it's just formatting again with 14.04.

Comment: Since the person who asked the question has corrected their answer to say that they would like to downgrade to 14.04 LTS, perhaps your answer should include some info on doing that.